# How to stream a websocket with spark streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, websocket, spark-streaming, databricks

I need to write a stream from a websocket to a parquet file using apache spark. The current apache spark streaming functionality doesn't seem to support websockets out of the box.

There is a command to read a stream from a TCP socket in apache-spark so I tried converting the websocket to a regular socket but haven't been able to get spark to read a socket yet with a test script:

I setup a server like so:

```py
import socket, socketserver, time

class MyHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        counter = 1
        while 1:
            #dataReceived = self.request.recv(1024)
            #if not dataReceived: break
            str_send = 'msg ' + str(counter)
            self.request.send(str_send.encode("utf-8"))
            counter+=1
            time.sleep(2)

myServer = socketserver.TCPServer(('localhost',5146), MyHandler)
myServer.serve_forever(  )
```

Which works fine with a normal client:

```py
import socket, socketserver, time
def client(ip, port):
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.connect((ip, port))
    while True:
        response = str(sock.recv(1024))
        print("Received: {}".format(response))

ip = 'localhost'
port = 5146
client(ip, port)
```

But when I use spark's example to read a TCP stream, I still get no data:

```py
lines = spark \
    .readStream \
    .format("socket") \
    .option("host", "localhost") \
    .option("port", 5146) \
    .load()

query = lines.writeStream\
      .format("console")\
      .outputMode('append')\
      .start()\
      .awaitTermination()
```

I also tried writing to a file but the file is blank.

The connection is established but no data is coming through:

```
$ netstat -na | grep "5146"
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.5146         127.0.0.1.59823        ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.59823        127.0.0.1.5146         ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.5146         *.*                    LISTEN
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Any Success here or Any update on how it can be done.